# Redux toolkit combineReducers problem.:Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Pls tell me what I did wrong?
configureStore.js:

```
import {configureStore, combineReducers} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import pokemonSearchSlice from "./slices/pokemonSearch";

const reducer = combineReducers({
pokemonSearch: pokemonSearchSlice
});

const store = configureStore({
reducer
});



export default store;
```

pokemonSearch.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";



const pokemonSearchSlice = createSlice({
    name: "pokemonSearch",
    initialState: {
        searchInputValue: ""
    },
    reducers: {
setValue:(state, action)=>({...state, searchInputalue: action.payload})
    }
}) ;



export const {setValue} = pokemonSearchSlice.actions;

export default pokemonSearchSlice;
```

Full text of error: redux.js:394 Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.
Also I'm not able to get that "searchInputValue" from the store, console says :Cannot destructure property 'searchInputValue' of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined.
But I think it's because of combineReducers error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few issues here:

- `configureStore` automatically calls `combineReducers` for you, so you don't want to do that directly.
- `configureStore`'s `reducer` object needs reducers, but you're passing it a slice. (The slice *contains* a reducer, but the slice itself is not a reducer.)
- Your `setValue` is returning a new object, but RTK uses Immer, so you should mutate the state passed into the function and not return anything.

In the end your code should look like this:

```js
// configureStore.js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import pokemonSearchSlice from "./slices/pokemonSearch";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    pokemon: pokemonSearchSlice,
  },
});

export default store;
```

```js
// slices/pokemonSearch.js"
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const pokemonSearchSlice = createSlice({
  name: "pokemonSearch",
  initialState: {
    searchInputValue: "",
  },
  reducers: {
    setValue: (state, action) => {
      state.searchInputValue = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setValue } = pokemonSearchSlice.actions;

export default pokemonSearchSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Thank you OG! Looks like I was using outdated tutorial, now everything works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the reducer from the slice, like this

```
const pokemonSearchSlice = createSlice({
  name: "pokemonSearch",
  initialState: {
    searchInputValue: ""
  },
  reducers: {
    setValue: (state, action) => ({ ...state, searchInputalue: action.payload })
  }
});

const { actions, reducer } = pokemonSearchSlice;
export const {setValue} = actions;
export default reducer
```

Comment: Thank you, buddy! Your suggestion about reducer is right, but reducer's code still needs to be changed, like Jimmy showed below.